# How to give dynamic height to UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have got a `UITableView` in my code

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0))
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier") as UITableViewCell!

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.comments[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

And i want to give a dynamic height to this UITableView.I tried two things

```
   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

   tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tableView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
```

And none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need use the below line of code once you set the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

```
tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tableView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
```

The issue could be your `autolayout` constraint which does not seems to be proper. So you need to make sure that you have pinned leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint properly inside your `tableViewCell` objects.

> Note:- If you are using UILabel then set number of lines = 0.

Comment: i only have top,left and right constraints without bottom for `UITableView` and inside the cell i don't have anything except a text

Comment: You need to set the bottom constraint as well. Otherwise your tableViewcell will not resize properly.

Comment: but that'll automatically define it's height won't it? I tried pinning it's bottom to it's parent UIView and it just resized to it's parent's height

Comment: So automatic dimension will work if it has proper leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint. Otherwise layout will not adjust its height automatically.

Comment: And also you need to make sure that your UILabel has number of lines = 0

Comment: So what should i set bottomAnchor to?

Comment: You need to set to your tableViewCell?

Comment: Nope to UITableview

Comment: So here is the issue set it to your cell.